# Properly resetting contents (including audio that is playing) of iframe added with write command

Tags: javascript, iframe, html5-audio

I use the open, write and close commands to insert content into an iframe.

For example:

```
var previewFrame = document.getElementById(id);
var preview = previewFrame.contentDocument || previewFrame.contentWindow.document;
preview.open();
preview.write('<!doctype html>\n<audio autoplay><source src="/audio/test.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>');
preview.close();
```

When I go to insert new content into that iframe, any audio that is currently playing in the background continues to play.

Is there any way to clear the contents of an iframe in a way that stops audio objects from playing.

Comment: Here is a link to an example you can try that demonstrates the problem. https://www.codeavengers.com/web/7?c=mike&f=iframe-audio.html

Comment: Yes, there is, perhaps you missed [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API)